# Get RSA private key from certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, rsa, private-key

I have a GlobalSign ssl certificate and opening it in Microsoft Management Console, it states "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate."

How do I read that private key in the following format as I need it for a key exchange:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.....
.....
.....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Are you writing a program? In which programming language?

Comment: Unless you are generating the key and the CSR yourself I don't think you can. You can however export the cert with the private key as a pfx which you can then read into a program and pull the private key from that, then using PEM format you, you'll be able to read it as such.